# How to preinstall a chrome extension on a linux headless server

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, headless

I need to install a chrome extension on a headless Server. 
One way is using group policy. I am looking for some other way of doing this.

For Firefox I would just place my XPI ( extension ) in the profile directory/extensions folder and Firefox would pick the extension . I wonder if for chrome I can do something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly what I was looking for. Found the answer here.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html

Comment: Alas, while you found the answer, the link is now dead :(

Answer (score -1):

- If you are installing from a file, make the .crx extension file available to the machine you want to install the extension on.
- Create a file with the following name in one of the folders listed below: aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc.json where the file name (without the extension) corresponds to your extension's ID. The location depends on the operating system.

**`Linux:`**

> /opt/google/chrome/extensions/  /usr/share/google-chrome/extensions/

**`Note:`** Use chmod if necessary to make sure that the aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc.json files are world-readable.

- Save the JSON file.
- Launch Google Chrome and go to chrome://extensions; you should see the extension listed.

## Reference

- [Hosting](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting.html)

Comment: Sudarshan : What should be the content of the <extensionID>.json File. Can you please share a sample json file which can be used here. Thanks.

Comment: <extensionID> is the string you observe when you package a extension