# Chrome extension .crx not installing on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to install a .crx Chrome extension via a .json preferences file as outlined on this page: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions
There is also a stackoverflow question that is [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196274/how-to-preinstall-a-chrome-extension-on-a-linux-headless-server/15196394#15196394) with the same information which basically said to add the preferences file to the directory and relaunch chrome.

I have found neither of these methods to work. I am using ubuntu 14.04 Chrome Version 44.0.2403.125 (64-bit). The actual location of the extensions on ubuntu is ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions///

I have checked the trouble shooting, made sure my .json is correct, made files 644 world readable. I have installed the extension by using the browser and loading it unpacked and it works fine. I tried the deprecated preferences file listed on the chrome site above external_extensions.json but this did not work either. Additionally, chrome does list the Profile Path    as ~/.config/google-chrome/Default

Comment: It looks like you're using the newest version of Chrome. I don't think Chrome supports this method of installing extensions anymore. Did you try just installing a folder containing the extension in developer mode?

Comment: The documentation does indicate Linux is still supporting it; Windows hasn't for awhile and Mac doesn't as of Chrome 44, so I am sure it's time is limited, but it should work now.  Are there any more details to this?  When you say it doesn't work, are you getting an error?

Comment: @Brian There is no error, I just restart chrome and it does not show up on the extensions page.

Comment: @ThePCLuddite Yes as I said above I did install by loading the unpacked folder containing the extension files in the browser in developer mode.