# Chrome Debugging Protocol: block hostnames (cancel network request)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

Through Chrome Debugging Protocol (or maybe a command-line flag), is there a way to block some hostnames (i.e. cancel any network request to them) in a Chrome headless instance using a remote proxy?

I suppose doing so via the local `hosts` file will work, but it won't have any affect if using a remote proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be possible to do this with the Chrome Debugging Protocol. There's an experimental feature in the web inspector, which exposes a `Request blocking` tab. Here you can block network requests, given a particular match criteria.

[image: Request blocking]

The Debugging Protocol has an [addBlockedURL](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Network/#method-addBlockedURL) method under the Network domain, which takes a URL as a parameter. It's an experimental API, but I think the current way you could do this is to do a regex match on the request URLs and pass each matched URL to the method. I suspect the new web inspector feature implements it along these lines.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose the `addBlockedURL` method accepts one URL at a time, but can it be called multiple times during a single page load?

Comment: @Nick I've not really tested this yet so I could be slightly wrong here. If you do try it out, let us know if it works out. Otherwise I'll schedule some time to look myself.

Comment: No worries, I'll give it a try soon, and share the findings.

Comment: Just confirming that multiple `addBlockedURL` statements can be specified, and moreover, the method accepts a full URL or a partial/fuzzy value with/without wildcards (e.g. host.*).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this using the remote debugging protocol.

The typical way to do block web requests to certain hostnames (or based on any other criteria!) is by installing an extension which uses the [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API to intercept and cancel requests. This is how ad-blocking extensions work, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, would you know if it's possible to use an extension in Chrome headless mode (maybe via a command-line parameter)?

Comment: Never mind, found a way to run extensions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196274/how-to-preinstall-a-chrome-extension-on-a-linux-headless-server